# How to remove brackets from a data file

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import

I would like to know how I can transform a file (.dat) that contains

```
{x1,x2, x3, x4, 
 x5, x6, x7, x8}
{y1,y2, y3, y4, 
 y5, y6, y7, y8}
```

in another file (.dat) that contains

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8
y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8
```

Comment: Does the existing file look ***exactly*** the way you show it? That is, does its 1st line have linefeed character after rightmost comma and does the 2nd line begins a single space?

Comment: Can you just do `Export[secondFile, Import[firstFile, "Package"], "Table"]`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using text manipulations.

```
data = Import["test.dat", "Text"]
```

> `"{x1,x2, x3, x4, 
>    x5, x6, x7,x8}
>   {y1,y2, y3, y4, 
>    y5, y6, y7,y8}"`

```
data2 = "{" <> StringReplace[StringReplace[data, WhitespaceCharacter -> ""], 
   "}{" -> "},{"] <> "}"
```

> `"{{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8},{y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8}}"`

```
Export["test.txt", ToExpression[data2], "Table"];
```

The resulting text file looks like this:
[image]